# 'npm install' extremely slow on Windows

Tags: node.js, windows, npm, build

For me is `npm install` extremely slow. I'm using Windows 8.1 with the latest npm version. My connection speed is around 100Mbit/s.

The project I'm trying to install has around 20 packages/dependencies and it takes around 30 Minutes to install all dependencies ...

Does anyone have a clue?

Comment: I'm having this issue today too. Reasonably freshly built windows 8.1 box, I installed node.js and npm today. npm install is running very slow when trying to install bower.
npm v2.7.4
nodejs v0.12.2

Comment: @Simon Knittel Have you solved it ?

Comment: @PantaRhei I don't know if it is the solution but it made a difference for me whether I install the modules on an USB3 drive or an internal HDD.

Comment: @simon it can be your firewall blocking connection otherwise make you update Nodejs and npm

Comment: @Pnta you can try update Nodejs and npm and disable firewall

Comment: Brah.. same here. I am planning on migrating to mac. It has the best of both worlds(Unix and pro apps).

Comment: I unplugged from my networks ethernet and used wifi. This sped the installation 1,000x

Answer (score 44):

I ran into the same problem, using `--verbose` as peterh mentioned showed me the source of the problem: I am behind a proxy, which uses its own certificates for https-connections. 
According to user "Mletter1" on https://github.com/npm/npm/issues/8872 the issue is quite easily solved by using http:

```
npm config set registry http://registry.npmjs.org/ --global
```

And voilà, it's fast again. Of course you should only do this, if you're ok with cleartext npm infos over the net ;-)

Comment: Just ran into this when using Windows WSL against a VirtualBox Docker (Toolbox). NPM slow as mud, redirecting my WSL (debian) to http npmjs.org sped things up significantly.

Comment: To add another helpful link, looks like WSL NPM usage is also impacted by Windows Defender. https://gist.github.com/noelbundick/9c804a710eb76e1d6a234b14abf42a52

Comment: But isn't that unsafe? Exposes you the MIM attacks

Comment: Great answer! However, now it is required to use https: `npm config set registry https://registry.npmjs.org/ --global`

Answer (score 43):

**Warning regarding security: this is an insecure approach if you don't use any other means of antivirus protection.**

From eternity → to **5  seconds builds**:

- search for ***Windows Defender settings***
- → Virus & threat protection
- → Virus & threat protection Settings
- → Exclusions

here add this two paths to your list of excluded *realtime protection* folders:

```
C:\Program Files\nodejs
C:\Users\<your username>\AppData\Roaming\npm
```

**PS**: replace the `<your username>` with your respective *User* folder name; or use [alias to the *AppData* folder](https://superuser.com/a/217506/64153) like: `%AppData%\npm`
If you're wondering why you can't find the *AppData* folder in Explorer, make sure to check *"View"* options for *"Show hidden folders"*.

Comment: It works great for me, should also add in the workspace folder, where you have local node_modules folders for projects.

Comment: @Chet let me know when *you make it work* what you did

Comment: I went into the defender and turned off all virus and threat protection, all network and firewall protection, turned off "check apps and files". I also turned added some npm settings to turn of progress, and set the registry url to http instead of https. Its a bit faster now.

Comment: @Chet yap, viruses infections should go faster now 

Comment: That's the plan! 

Comment: you save my day

Comment: This is for me the best answer.

Comment: Just type in %appdata% in your explorer. Will take  you to roaming folder

Comment: Why NodeJS build is considered harmful by anti-virus?

Comment: If you are using nvm for windows you should change the path to "C:\Users\<your username>\AppData\Roaming\nvm"

Answer (score 13):

I know its just a **workaround**, but try using the build-in "[Windows PowerShell](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee248590(v=vs.100).aspx)"

Comment: Worked fine! Thanks.

Comment: @MartinDoes Why is PowerShell faster?

Comment: Same exact performance between `cmd.exe` and PowerShell for me.

Comment: But, why, can we know why.

Answer (score 10):

I've been facing the same issue for a while. I was trying out the following

```
npm i typescript live-server --save-dev
```

The install would get stuck at it forever. However adding the -verbose flag worked just fine.

Comment: But why `-verbose` makes a difference?

Answer (score 5):

It seems like npm do not deal well with internet connections and can sometimes end in such situation.

**1)** I'll advice you to check if your firewall or antivirus is not performing any scan or filtering which may slow down npm install.

**2)** You may also use caching from npm like below.

```
npm install package-name --cache "c:\path\to\use\as\dependencies\cache"
```

this will allow npm download and cache dependencies in the directory you specified.

**3)** another solution for caching npm packages dependencies is **npm lazy**, you may find more information about this at [npm Lazy website](http://mixu.net/npm_lazy/)

**Note:** the caching process may or may not improve the download speed but it will probably save downloads time when installing or updating your npm packages.

Answer (score 4):

For me it appeared to be a problem with IPv6.

Disabling IPv6 helped immensely for me.
With IPv6 turned on "update-package newtonsoft.json" took 1:45 to time out with the error "update-package : A task was canceled."

With IPv6 disabled "update-package newtonsoft.json" completed in 10 seconds

Comment: Disabling IPv6 helped me with similar issue on Fedora 23

Answer (score 3):

Turning off Windows Firewall and Windows Defender Real-time protection did it for me in Windows 10.

Comment: this would disable basic protection of the whole computer. [Roko's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51827314/588868) reduce the exposure to only node folders.

Answer (score 3):

Fully turning off virus and firewall protection isn't the safest option. While it makes things faster, it leaves you more vulnerable.

In my case, I only excluded the node.exe process in virus & threat protection.

- In your start menu, type "windows security" and open the app.
- Click on "Virus & threat protection"
- Virus & threat protection settings => Manage settings
- Exclusions => Add or remove exclusions
- Add an exclusion => process => type node.exe => click Add

just a simple create-react-app went down from 2m40s to 1m10s
npm commands are also executed by node.exe, so the same improvements are noticed there.

Answer (score 2):

I faced the same issue while creating project while using angular cli "ng new PROJECT_NAME" this command triggers "npm -install" after creation of project, which took too long to install, and got stuck at "Installing packages for tooling via npm" . Follow these which worked for me

1) Check your npm version "npm --version" (must be higher than 2.1.8)Update your npm package by "npm -g install --save latest-version"

2) Remove the progress bar which consumes more time "npm set progress=false"

check this issues if still doesn't fix your problem 
https://github.com/nodejs/node/issues/4150
https://github.com/npm/npm/issues/11283

Hopefully this sorts the problem Cheers!

Answer (score 2):

In my case it was due to over 200 vulnerabilities. When I ran

```
npm audit fix
```

that solved only just a few of them. Eventually, I had to run

```
npm audit fix --force
```

and it got way better than before.

Answer (score 1):

I tried all the config's (proxy, registry, etc) nothing worked for me, so did a complete uninstall and install node & npm. Which helped to solve the issue.

Answer (score 1):

Turning off the Windows Defender Firewall helped for me.

Because it just doesnt feel right I first added the WIFI to a Private Network (via WIFI settings) and only turned off the Windows Defender for a Private Network instead of all public Networks.

The next step should be: what network traffic causes this and how to add this to the Windows Defender exception rule :)

Answer (score 1):

in addition to all other great comments, I'd also suggest switching to yarn (https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=geeklearningio.gl-vsts-tasks-yarn).
using devops (selfhosted agent v.2.192.0), with node (v.14.17.6), we were able to trim total build (install + build) from ~10min to ~6-7 min.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you really are using a recent version of npm. In my case `C:\Program Files\nodejs\npm.cmd` had been using an old `npm-cli.js` below the default `prefix` folder `%appdata%\npm` rather than a newer `npm-cli.js` below `C:\Program Files\nodejs`.

Setting the [environment variable](https://docs.npmjs.com/using-npm/config#environment-variables) `npm_config_prefix` to `C:\Program Files\nodejs` solved  that. (Before finding that solution, I tried using the `--prefix` [argument](https://docs.npmjs.com/using-npm/config#shorthands-and-other-cli-niceties) and found out the hard way doing so *"[forces non-global commands to run in the specified folder](https://docs.npmjs.com/using-npm/config.html#prefix)"*.)

I found a huge performance increase going from 3.10.9 to 6.13.4-- enough to make `npm install` times acceptable despite interference from antivirus.

Answer (score 0):

I just went through a rabbit hole trying to identify the issue. If npm install keeps getting bottlenecked you should heavily consider modifying the properties of your virtual ethernet and disable all of the **offload** items.

I had 0 proxies or caching issues with npm.

See here for the tutorial on how to get to the menu and disable your offload settings. Make sure you do this for both your your ethernet and VEthernet and you should immediately notice a difference. I went from a 10 minute hanging resolution that sometimes just stopped down to 10 seconds installs.
https://www.dincloud.com/blog/tuning-windows-get-15x-speeds-on-large-file-copies-today

Answer (score 0):

This is highly situational but we have a local registry (`npm config get registry`)  that was not available (VPN:d) in when I was running the `npm install ...` and this obviously made it very slow but it still succeeded because everything was still available through cache.

Answer (score 0):

**Try upgrading to the latest Node.js version**. I was originally using the most recent LTS (18.x) and downloading packages was painfully slow. I then tried installing the latest 20.x and it instantly solved my download issues.

You may also try adding the `--verbose` flag (e.g. `npm install --verbose`) to have an idea on where the process is getting stuck.