# npm install package-name is very slow

Tags: javascript, npm, ecmascript-6, npm-install, babeljs

I'm running this command: `npm install babel-preset-es2015 --save-dev`, but it is very slow!

Also, Execute other codes (code below) has done very slow:

`npm init`
`npm install babel-cli babel-core --save-dev`

I got this link to help fix the problem, but the problem is not resolved:

['npm install' extremely slow on Windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29395211/npm-install-extremely-slow-on-windows)

I'm using Windows 10 and Git Bash to run commands with the latest npm version.

Who can help?

Comment: Have you tried `yarn` instead? it also installs node modules but really fast compared to using `npm`

Comment: what is the difference between this question and the question you have linked yourself?

Comment: Check you have latest node module and your internet speed and all

Comment: @OlegEstekhin The best answer to that question is related to at least one year in advance! I hope that friends offer a new solution.

Comment: Possible duplicate of ['npm install' extremely slow on Windows](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29395211/npm-install-extremely-slow-on-windows)

Comment: What version of npm are you using?

Comment: @loganfsmyth I've installed `npm` today. The final version.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try **Yarn**
https://yarnpkg.com/en/

It will be faster than **npm**

Comment: Yes, It's faster than **npm**. Certainly not the problem of npm servers.This problem is related to Windows.

Comment: My internet connection is not the problem. If the speed of the Internet. Why when using ‍`Yarn` well does it work?

Comment: Try `npm cache clean` after that install the package globally `npm install g babel-cli babel-core`