# Why is WSL extremely slow when compared with native Windows NPM/Yarn processing?

Tags: ubuntu, npm, yarnpkg, windows-subsystem-for-linux, wsl-2

I am working with WSL a lot lately because I need some native UNIX tools (and emulators aren't good enough). I noticed that the speed difference when working with NPM/Yarn is incredible.

I conducted a simple test that confirmed my feelings. The test was running `npx create-react-app my-test-app` and the WSL result was `Done in 287.56s.` while GitBash finished with `Done in 10.46s.`.

This is not the whole picture, because the perceived time was higher in both cases, but even based on that - there is a big issue somewhere. I just don't know where. The project I'm working on uses tens of libraries and changing even one of them takes minutes instead of seconds.

Is this something that I can fix? If so - where to look for clues?

Additional info:

- my processor: Processor   AMD Ryzen 7 5800H with Radeon Graphics, 3201 Mhz, 8 Core(s), 16 Logical Processors
- I'm running Windows 11 with all the latest updates to both the system and the WSL. The chosen system is Ubuntu 20.04
- I've seen some questions that are somewhat similar like ['npm install' extremely slow on Windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29395211/npm-install-extremely-slow-on-windows), but they don't touch WSL at all (and my pure Windows NPM works fast).
- the issue is not limited to NPM, it's also for Yarn
- another problem that I'm getting is that file watching is not happening (I need to restart the server with every change). In some applications I don't get any errors, sometimes I get the following:

  ```
  Watchpack Error (initial scan): Error: EACCES: permission denied, lstat '/mnt/c/DumpStack.log.tmp'
  Watchpack Error (initial scan): Error: EACCES: permission denied, lstat '/mnt/c/hiberfil.sys'
  Watchpack Error (initial scan): Error: EACCES: permission denied, lstat '/mnt/c/pagefile.sys'
  Watchpack Error (initial scan): Error: EACCES: permission denied, lstat '/mnt/c/swapfile.sys'
  ```
- `npm start` in an empty (freshly initialized) `create-react-app` takes ages to render something in the browser in WSL and when executed from GitBash - I can see stuff in 2-4 seconds
- it is possible that's it's purely a WSL problem, but it just hurts the most when using NPM/Yarn

Comment: Yarn was slow in a Windows mounted folder (`/mnt/c`). Running yarn in a project within the Ubuntu home directory (`~`) made it much faster for me (Window 11, WSL2).

Comment: `git` commands was super slow in wsl 2. I converted to  wsl 1 and now its fine. Moving the project files to `/home/..` was not ideal for me in the current project. I will follow the second soultion for future.

Comment: I did the same as @Code_Ostrich. I use only WSL 1 for all development purpose and WSL2 only for the docker stuff.

Answer (score 169, accepted):

Since you mention executing the same files (with proper performance) from within Git Bash, I'm going to make an assumption here.

This would be explained (and expected) if your files are stored on `/mnt/c` (a.k.a. `C:`, or `/C` under Git Bash) or any other Windows drive, as they would likely need to be to be accessed by Git Bash.

WSL2 uses the 9P protocol to access Windows drives, and it is currently <sup>*(See Footnote)*</sup> known to be *very* slow when compared to:

- Native NTFS (obviously)
- The ext4 filesystem on the virtual disk used by WSL2
- And even the performance of WSL1 with Windows drives

I've seen a `git clone` of a large repo (the WSL2 Linux kernel Github) take 8 minutes on WSL2 on a Windows drive, but only seconds on the root filesystem.

Two possibilities:

- If possible (and it is for most Node projects), convert your WSL to version 1 with `wsl --set-version <distroname> 1`.  I always recommend making a backup with `wsl --export` first.

  And since you are making a backup anyway, you may as well just create a *copy* of the instance by `wsl --import`ing your backup as `--version 1` (as the last argument).  WSL1 and WSL2 both have their uses, and you may find it helpful to keep both around.

  See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66067679/11810933) for more details on the exact syntax..
- Or just move the project over to somewhere under the WSL root, such as `/home/username/src/`.

---

<sup>*Footnote*</sup>:

There may be some hope for improvement in this area based on recent developments.  Patches for 9P have been released upstream which are reported to provide a significant performance boost.  See [this Github thread comment](https://github.com/microsoft/WSL/discussions/9412#discussioncomment-5173052) (and the parent thread) for more information.

Comment: hey  
first of all - thank you very much for a comprehensive answer. and yes - all my files are stored under `/mnt/c`. I tried your 2nd solution - it worked as fast as expected in the terminal, but the IDE froze when I first loaded the `create-react-app` project [IntelliJ Ultimate]. interestingly enough, the second run was successful - I'll test more with my actual project. When it comes to switching to WSL1 - I vaguely remember that I needed to upgrade because WSL1 was missing some features that WSL2 had (I'm running Rust with the BPF compiler for Solana dev), so I can't do that

Comment: I'll move with my real project to `/home/username/...` and see how the IDE handles the whole thing. if it works - I'll be happy to accept your answer, for now I'll +1 it (as I believe it will probably help someone in the future - please don't delete it) 
disclaimer: yes, I use Rust as my main programming language for this project, but node is used for E2E testing and therefore it has both - hence I used npm as a more widely known example to depict the problem. also - some npm libs (for testing solana) work only under *nix systems

Comment: the IDE is considerably slower and freezes with more instances open (never happened before), but I guess it's fast enough and I'll just go with that solution for now. thank you :) 
  PS. do you happen to have any information on whether this issue might be addressed in the future or not? is there any github issue opened for it?

Comment: @WrRaThY Here's the main [issue](https://github.com/microsoft/WSL/issues/4197) for tracking, and while I've read statements from the Microsoft team that they aren't happy with the performance, I'm unaware of a root cause being mentioned (but I haven't read through all 350+ comments on the issue) other than perhaps the lack of caching support in 9P.

Comment: @WrRaThY Also, I didn't notice the "watching" part of your question earlier, but yes, that's also due to 9P.  See [this question/answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63455155/11810933) for more info on that.  Note that watching seems to work if you run the app from within VSCode, though.

Comment: thanks for all the support! I'm guessing that running from vscode = running from native windows filesystem, so this is probably why. I'll follow up on those links if it makes sense. cheers!

Comment: I can confirm, I just moved my whole project from `/mnt/c/...` to `/home/...` and the speed increase is astonishing.

Comment: My project is stored under /home/user/workspace/myproject and I'm running into performance issues. Sometimes it seems yarn install is stuck for a while until it processes further. Accessing the project with WebStorm under Windows 11 has also a lot of freezes.

Comment: For development WSL2 is a big nay. And not only it's super slow I had issues making file change detection works properly. Going back to v1..

Comment: @vdegenne WSL1 is a good option, but also remember that having the files on the WSL2 ext4 filesystem *should* give you both inotify support as well as near native file access speeds.

Comment: I ran into the same problem and created a video based on this and other related questions.
https://youtu.be/458YBx-Px-E

Comment: this explain why the NetBeans inside WSL is slow. Copy the NetBeans files to Linux dir, make it quite fast. Thanks, that is awesome!

Comment: @Harun Yup!  And you're welcome!  Every time there's a new WSL release, the first thing I check is whether the release notes indicate it has addressed the 9P performance ;-).  Also, thanks for the upvote - It gave me my first "Great Answer" gold badge here on SO.  :-)

Comment: The second one worked for me. Thanks a lot man!! Cheers!!

Comment: In addition to this. Install visual studio code (or other IDE) in wsl. This will speed up the whole process and I found git related colour changes in filename is working fine with this setup. I added a bat file in Desktop to run it in one click. put 'wsl code' in the bat file for that.

Comment: @ArjunG If I'm understanding you correctly, that shouldn't really help with this particular problem.  Regardless of whether you are running the Linux version of WSL or the Windows version, the fact that WSL2 has to access files in the *Windows* filesystem through 9P is going to drastically slow things down.  [Microsoft's recommendation](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/remote/wsl) is to use the *Windows* version of VSC in WSL2 rather than the Linux version (see *"Install Visual Studio Code on the Windows side (not in WSL)"*), and I tend to agree.

Comment: @NotTheDr01ds I had some trouble opening files in an Ubuntu system when using Windows version VSC. A speed difference between the filesystem and the VSC raised my doubts about that. So I gave using VSC with WSL a try, and it worked well. I am aware that this is a bad approach. However, since certain corporate laptops come with numerous windows restrictions, we can utilise it as a workaround.

Answer (score 85):

*Building on @notthedr01ds's reponse.*

If you look at Microsoft's [Comparing WSL 1 and WSL 2](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/compare-versions)  the '*Performance across the OS file systems*' is explicitly worse in WSL2.

[image: Comparison of WS1 and WSL2 from Comparing WSL 1 and WSL 2]

My case fell into [Exceptions for using WSL 1 rather than WSL 2](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/compare-versions#exceptions-for-using-wsl-1-rather-than-wsl-2)

> - Your project files must be stored in the Windows file system. WSL 1 offers faster access to files mounted from Windows.
>
>   - If you will be using your WSL Linux distribution to access project files on the Windows file system, and these files cannot be stored on the Linux file system, you will achieve faster performance across the OS files systems by using WSL 1.

This means I needed to swap to version 1.

```
wsl --set-version Ubuntu 1
Conversion in progress, this may take a few minutes...
Conversion complete.
```

#### Test before

```
>time git status
...
real    0m6.436s
user    0m0.055s
sys     0m36.380s
```

#### Test after

```
> time git status
...
real    0m0.126s
user    0m0.016s
sys     0m0.641s
```

Comment: according to https://vxlabs.com/2019/12/06/wsl2-io-measurements/  best performance is with WSL-2 running on ext4 (i.e. inside WSL-2) and not outside (i.e. NTFS).  They say it is faster than WSL-1 on lxfs or NTFS.

Answer (score 9):

I had exactly the same problem with WSL 2 on Windows 11. WSL uses two file systems, the WSL/Linux file system and the Windows file system.

What can be confusing is that by default the WSL prompt starts in

```
/mnt/c/Users/<username>
```

When you do a git clone in here what happens is the files are downloaded in the Windows filesystem. If you navigate in Windows to the Users/username directory you will find all your files here. The interaction between filesystems is done over a share (9P protocol). This is insanely slow. So if you are in a subdir of 'mnt' you are not using WSL filesystem.

Make sure after starting WSL you enter the WSL filesystem, e.g. your home dir

```
$ cd
```

If you clone here and start a build you will have the performance you'd expect.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/filesystems

---

edit:

I make sure wsl always starts on the local filesystem instead of wsl share. You can do this for any directory you like, I like to start in my git folder:

```
echo 'cd ~/git' >>~/.bashrc
```

Comment: `cd` is short for `cd ~` btw ;)

Comment: thx @0xC0000022L, have been using Windows for too long :)

Answer (score 5):

For those who wants to keep their **WSL version 2**, I got much better performence using a **NFS** server on Windows mounted on WSL.

#### Performence

- From the provided mounting point (2m06s)

```
> git status
...
git status  0.72s user 64.33s system 51% cpu 2:06.37 total
```

- From NFS mounting point (~2sec)

```
> git status
git status  0.45s user 0.12s system 31% cpu 1.828 total
```

#### How to

I used a free software https://www.hanewin.net/nfs-e.htm (I downloaded the application not the service, as I don't have admin rights on my laptop)
And closed the port on my firewall.

Add the folder you want to access on the NFS server :

[image]

Then it's just a line in `/etc/fstab`

```
172.18.192.1:/c/Users/.../IdeaProjects /home/.../IdeaProjects nfs defaults 0 0
```

Reboot wsl2 or mount the folder:

```
sudo mount /home/.../IdeaProjects
```

Done.

Comment: Thanks for adding this - I've been meaning to update my answer with similar info, but haven't had the chance yet.  And it's better coming from someone who's tried it anyway, which I haven't yet.  Also (for other readers), according to the Github issue thread I linked, other file servers may also work for this.  Still hoping that the WSL dev team can make some direct improvements in 9P performance, though :-)

Answer (score 2):

#### Quick Fix: For those whose office closes in an hour

in reference to idea proposed by Erwan,

> Or just move the project over to somewhere under the WSL root, such as /home/username/src/.

use this hack, while opening vscode folder use this path

`\\wsl.localhost\ubuntu\home\user\<your_github_project>` ,

this works because wsl does some network mounting to bridge the files, so open project directly at the host(linux) env.

[image]

and do your stuff. this is more effecient as the project is guarenteed to open in "dedicated" file system, and if you open a new shell

```
ctrl + `
```

will give

```
Microsoft.PowerShell.Core\FileSystem::\\wsl.localhost\ubuntu\home\user\<project_folder_name>
```

`rsync -av /mnt/somewhere ./here --exclude node_modules` will do migration incase you have previously setup project at "c:github/myrepo/" . else just copy paste in explorer or drag and drop.

### tests done:

> before: runtime=bun framework=svelt-kit task="load homepage 10 times " time taken="1.6 seconds/call"

> before:node: 3.4s/call which is a tortoise

> after-migration:bun: Average time: 0.13610472679138183s |

### Result : 10x speedup

SCRIPT USED:

```py
import time
import requests
URL = "http://localhost:5173/"
times = []
for i in range(5):
    start = time.time()
    requests.get(URL)
    end = time.time()
    times.append(end - start)

print("Average time: {}".format(sum(times) / len(times)))
```

Summary: using this method vscode now access the files directly from the wsl , rather using the slower filesystem.

Answer (score 1):

My issues got solved when I did checkout from ubuntu machine only and then running yarn/npm run finished quickly. Earlier I was doing git clone inside windows folder and running yarn/npm command from ubuntu.

Answer (score 0):

It may be due to network slowness when downloading packages from network.

There are a couple of bugs reported. Here are some links:

[Very slow network speed on WSL2 · Issue #4901](https://github.com/microsoft/WSL/issues/4901)

[Very slow network speeds #8171 - microsoft/WSL](https://github.com/microsoft/WSL/issues/8171)

[low internet speed in WSL 2](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/all/low-internet-speed-in-wsl-2/21524829-18be-4611-bb5f-cabccd2cae31)

[WSL 2 — How To Fix Download Speed | by Chris Townsend](https://townsyio.medium.com/wsl2-how-to-fix-download-speed-3edb0c348e29)

Etc.

Note that Windows 11 does not show virtual adapters so I had to apply the workaround using Powershell as Administrator:

```
 PS C:\WINDOWS\system32> Enable-NetAdapterLso -Name vEthernet* -IncludeHidden -IPv4
 PS C:\WINDOWS\system32> Enable-NetAdapterLso -Name vEthernet* -IncludeHidden -IPv6                                           PS
```