# How to speed up ViteJs development mode

Tags: javascript, typescript, vue.js, vuejs3, vite

The problem is that in development mode, the server is mega slow.

I start the server, then start the page in the browser and wait 3–6 minutes for the page to load!
Initially, ViteJs downloads a few kilobytes of resources, then the request is in the "pending" state for 2–3 minutes.

Then, the loading of all resources starts every time. Although I also specified in the config that all CSS should be local.

Page reloading is also very slow.

I start the project like this:

```
vite
```

Here is my config:

```
import {defineConfig} from 'vite'
import vue from '@vitejs/plugin-vue'
import {resolve} from 'path'

export default defineConfig({
  plugins: [vue()],
  resolve: {
    alias: {
      "@": resolve(__dirname, "./src"),
    },
  },
  publicDir: 'public',
  server: {
    port: 8080,
    watch: {
      usePolling: true,
      ignored: ['!**/bundle/**', '!**/lib/**']
    }
  },
  css: {
    modules: {
      scopeBehaviour: "local"
    }
  },
  preview: {
    port: 8080,
  }
})
```

Answer (score 7):

The problem is in WSL2.

I tried to start Vite from Windows, and start page loaded in 1 second!

Comment: Can you tell a bit more about it what does it mean "start vite from Windows"? You turned off WSL2 on windows?

Comment: Yes. Just start npm/node process(npm run dev for example) from Windows cmd/powerShell.

Comment: I agree. Start your npm run dev in cmd or Powershell. It's a hell lot faster. I used to run mine in VSCode.

Comment: This hasn't solved my problem, on my side it still works slowly, even after running dev server from PowerShell :/ Any other ideas, why could it be?

Comment: The problem could have been caused by the fact that Vite was running on Windows, but the files were accessible on WSL2 running Linux, or vice versa. The main issue is the slow write speed between the WSL2 and Windows file systems. Vite.js creates a cache, builds the project, and immediately updates it live if there are any changes in the source code. --> So Vite performs a lot of writing, especially during development.

Comment: It's important to note that if you store your project on a Windows system, it's advisable to also start the development server from Windows. If you store your project on WSL2 with installed Linux, then run Vite there as well. This way, you can avoid the lingering slow file write issue with WSL2. [More information - another stackoverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68974497/15167500) - [WSL Github Issue](https://github.com/microsoft/WSL/issues/4197#issuecomment-1400282463)

Answer (score 1):

Vite is not a suitable tool for large projects (with 1000+ source files), because it does not bundle the source code for you during development, and in order to reload, your browser needs to make thousands of requests.