# nvm with WSL for projects stored in Windows

Tags: node.js, ubuntu, windows-subsystem-for-linux, nvm

I'm struggling to understand how exactly WSL works.

The training that I'm doing requires `nvm` so I can manage my node versions in my project, located in my hard drive that is running with Windows.

So, in order to use `nvm` I need WSL, but I cannot comprehend where it is located. As far as I understood (and I'm pretty sure that I'm wrong) the WSL that I installed is like a Linux VM, completely independent from my Windows, and I operate it through the Ubuntu Terminal that came with WSL. If that's the case, how can `nvm` in WSL be useful if my project is in my Windows directory and the WSL controls node versions from my Linux VM?

How do I make `nvm` useful for my project running from my `C:\` drive and how does WSL work with `nvm` in my Windows?

Thank you!

Comment: Are you using WSL1 or WSL2?

Comment: nvm is the tool for you to manage Node.js installation on a machine (in your case, Windows). Why do you need WSL here? So far, this question makes no sense to me. WSL is a virtualized Linux environment mostly separated from Windows (with some integration), so you don't need to learn/use it if Windows is all you wanted.

Comment: Sorry, I'm new in this, and the only way I could find to install nvm was through WSL. I installed WSL using "wsl --install --online Ubuntu", and I don't know if this WSL 1 or 2. 
So, I assume that what I said was correct, except for the part that I was using WSL to install nvm.
Is there a way to install nvm in my windows without WSL?
Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A few options, but each has advantages and disadvantages:

- If your Node/JavaScript files are on your Windows `C:\` drive, then you do have the ability to access that from WSL.  Windows paths are automatically mounted and accessible in WSL via `/mnt/c`, `/mnt/d`, etc.

  So if you have your JS source in, for example:

  ```
  C:\Users\<myusername>\Documents\Projects\JS_class\project1\
  ```

  Then that would be accessible under Ubuntu in WSL via:

  ```
  /mnt/Users/<myusername>/Documents/Projects/JS_class/project1/
  ```

  The disadvantage here is performance, as mentioned in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68974497/11810933).
- Alternatively, you can store your project files inside WSL.  You can access the WSL path from Windows by using `\\wsl$\Ubuntu\home\<yourusername>\` (or similar).  You can use this to copy from your existing Windows drive to your WSL distribution.

  Advantage: Faster.  Disadvantage: Unknown -- You seem to want the files to be in Windows, but I'm not sure why.
- Or you can use WSL1 for most Node/JS tasks.  See the [previously mentioned answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68974497/11810933) for details on how to convert.

  Advantage: Speed

  Disadvantage: WSL1 hasn't been updated in a while, and is started to run into some compatibility issues.  It's still popular enough and stable enough at the moment for me to continue to recommend it, though.
- There's also a [Windows version of nvm](https://github.com/coreybutler/nvm-windows) as well as a replacement project that the repo there mentions.  I cannot personally speak for the quality of it, but it does have 23k stars on Github.  Note that it is *not* affiliated with the original (Linux-based) `nvm` project.

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer! I appreciate your attention.