# VsCode Run DevContainer on WSL does not increase its perfomance

Tags: python, windows-subsystem-for-linux, vscode-devcontainer

I am trying to run a 2gb file into a VsCode Dev container in Windows and it takes more than 3 minutes just to open it and read it (I am using python language).

I read docker in windows is very slow so if I want to improve its performance I have to run it through WSL. This is the guide I followed:

1. check WSL installation: on command prompt run wsl - - status
2. installing WSL :  How to Install WSL2 on Windows 11 (Windows Subsystem for Linux)
3. Oracle Linux Installation: wsl.exe - - install -d OracleLinux_8_7
4. Set OracleLinux as default distribution: wsl -s OracleLinux_8_7
5. From DockerDesktop: Settings(next to sign in) => Resources => WSL Integration => Enable
   integration with additional distros => OracleLinux_8_7
6. From a new command prompt: wsl
7. Installing git: sudo dnf install git
8. clone the repository
9. Activating VsCode: enter in the git report (cd/repo_name) and type code .
10. click on Reopen in Container

As I was expecting, the script opened the file in few seconds (3 or 4); on the left side of VsCode I could see: "mnt/c/Users/path_to_my_folder [WSL:OracleLinux_8_7].

I rebooted my computer and typed wsl on command prompt; then I went to my folder directory and then I type code . and I clicked on  ReopenDevContainer. On the left side I did not see my linux directory anymore (PROJECTNAME: DockerExistingFile) and when I launched my script it took more than 4 minutes to be executed. It seems my container is no longer running on linux; how can I fix that?

## Solution

The solution was very easy, typing wsl from command line it brings me into my windows user directory so I just had to do: cd /home/my_user_linux

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why is WSL extremely slow when compared with native Windows NPM/Yarn processing?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68972448/why-is-wsl-extremely-slow-when-compared-with-native-windows-npm-yarn-processing)

Comment: the guide that I posted has been written following that article