# Long execution times for executing python/pip commands in virtual env of WSL2

Tags: python, pip, wsl-2

Can anyone explain this weird long execution times for getting versions of pip (And of course other pip-related commands) on WSL2? And potentially a workaround for it?

#### When on a virtual environment (venv) (32 seconds!)

```
(venv) root@mohsen:/mnt/c# time python -V
Python 3.11.6

real    0m0.013s
user    0m0.007s
sys     0m0.000s
(venv) root@mohsen:/mnt/c# time pip -V
pip 23.2.1 from /mnt/c/project/venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/pip (python 3.11)

real    0m32.380s
user    0m2.007s
sys     0m4.177s
```

#### When `venv` is deactivated: (2secs)

```
root@mohsen:/mnt/c# time python -V
Python 3.11.6

real    0m0.278s
user    0m0.206s
sys     0m0.112s
root@mohsen:/mnt/c# time pip -V
pip 23.2.1 from /root/.asdf/installs/python/3.11.6/lib/python3.11/site-packages/pip (python 3.11)

real    0m2.012s
user    0m1.360s
sys     0m0.439s
```

Answer (score 4):

*Short answer:*  Keep your Venv in the Linux filesystem, not the Windows one.

*More Detail:*

I can reproduce this to some degree, and it looks to be the same root problem I mention in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68974497/11810933).  Also see the [WSL Doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/filesystems) on the topic.

When running in the Venv, you are using a Python installation in:

```
/mnt/c/project/venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/pip
```

Being on the Windows filesystem, that's going to be *substantially* slower than the native, non-venv version running on the Linux (virtual) filesystem in:

```
/root/.asdf/installs/python/3.11.6/lib/python3.11/site-packages/pip
```

`time pip -V` isn't quite that slow for me (4.82s under the Venv), but that's still about 20x slower than the non-Venv invocation.  That may be due to the number of packages you have installed in the Venv - I tried it on a newly created one.  You'll find that the Windows filesystem's performance is much worse under WSL2 as the number of files (especially small ones) increases.

On the other hand, the initial Venv creation is quite slow for me on the Windows filesystem:

```
> time python3 -m venv .venv

________________________________________________________
Executed in   45.67 secs    fish           external
   usr time    2.30 secs   59.00 micros    2.30 secs
   sys time    9.57 secs  301.00 micros    9.57 secs
```

However, under my Linux home directory:

```
> time python3 -m venv .venv

________________________________________________________
Executed in    2.23 secs    fish           external
   usr time    1.97 secs   56.00 micros    1.97 secs
   sys time    0.22 secs  288.00 micros    0.22 secs
```

*Alternative:*

One alternative to moving the files to the WSL2 virtual filesystem is to use WSL1 where performance is pretty much on par regardless of the filesystem.

Comment: +1, I was having the same problem my first time with WSL - you should definitely keep your venv in the Linux filesystem.

Comment: I can't move to WSL1 since I'm using Docker for my project. 
Can't move to WSL file system as well because I tried it once and I couldn't make it work seamlessly with VScode...
I think I'm stuck until they fix the WSL problem :)

Comment: @MohsenTaleb I don't see any recent questions from you on the VSCode problem, so you might want to post that as a separate question.  In my experience, VSCode works great with the Linux filesystem in WSL2 (and is Microsoft's recommendation as well).  However, there are always corner cases, so you might be running into something that is (hopefully) fixable there.